# how to query mongodb in this case

Tags: mongodb, find

I have following content in the collection:

```
{
    "Tom": {
    "age": 20,
    "address": "xxx"
    },
    "John": {
    "age": 23,
    "address": "xxx"
    },
    ...
}
```

How do I write the command in mongodb shell or another piece of software to find people's address whose age is greater than N?

Comment: Is that a single document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to change your schema and store the documents in the below structure:

```
db.t.insert([{
"name":"Tom",
"age":20,
"address":"address1"
},
{
"name":"John",
"age":23,
"address":"address2"
}])
```

This makes querying very simple and straight forward:

```
db.t.find({"age":{$gt:20}})
```

When you have your documents, where the keys are highly variable data(`names`), it becomes nearly **impossible** to query dynamically. You will be able to query it using the `aggregation framework` though, but that comes at a cost. Just for the records, i would post the aggregation query to your current document structure.

```
var age = 20;
db.t.aggregate([
{$redact:{$cond:[{$gt:[{$ifNull:["$age",age+1]},age]},
                 "$$DESCEND","$$PRUNE"]}}
])
```

The query makes use of the [$redact](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#descend) stage alone and traverses and keeps all the sub documents within a document which meet the criteria in the [$cond](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) expression. The rest it discards.